# How to run containers in a swarm with filters using the Docker Remote API?

Tags: api, docker, docker-swarm

I want to run containers in my swarm with some [filters](https://docs.docker.com/v1.6/swarm/scheduler/filter/) using the Docker Remote API. E.g. I would like to use the REST API to do the same thing as this command:

```
$ docker run -d --name logger -e affinity:container==front logger
```

I know that the Swarm API is mostly compatible with the Docker Remote API and I read the [Remote API documentation](https://docs.docker.com/reference/api/docker_remote_api_v1.18/#create-a-container) but I can't find which parameters I have to use to create an equivalent command with the REST API.

Answer (score 0):

As the `-e` flag states, `affinity:container==front` is an environment variable thus the JSON parameter `Env` has to be used. In this example the parameter is:

```
{ "Env" = "affinity:container==front"}
```